# How to make installation default path to user desktop with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno setup for make a installation to my program.
And I would like to know, how to make the program to be installed in the user desktop by default?

I figured out, I need to use `DefaultDirName=`.

I need to know, what to write there for install to be on user desktop be default.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`{userdesktop}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userdesktop):

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={userdesktop}
```

---

You may also consider setting [`PrivilegesRequired`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) to `lowest`, as you probably do not need the installer to run with Administrator privileges.

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
```